# Command echo executes before read

Tags: bash

I wrote this code: 
   `read NAME | echo "$NAME"`
Unexpectedly, command echo executes before read, in this case it shows an empty line and then waits for me to enter the text. Does anyone know what to do if I want read to execute first?

Comment: pipes start passing and consuming data immediately, so echo *appears* to run first: try `read NAME && echo $NAME`

Comment: `read NAME && echo "$NAME"`

Answer (score 3):

A pipe is a communication channel between two processes, a writer and a reader.    The writer and reader can execute simultaneously, only needing to depend on each other for the write/read relationship.

For the pipe to do anything useful, the writer (the command on the left) needs to output something to its standard output (stdout), and the reader (the command on the right) needs to read from its standard input (stdin).  If the reader does not actually attempt to read from stdin, it will not block and will execute without waiting for the writer to do anything.

The pipe is an operating system mechanism that connects the writer's stdout with the reader's stdin without you, the programmer, having to bother with any detail regarding file descriptors, synchronization, and other boring and tricky details.  It is great but if you do not understand what happens behind the scene, it may produce results you will consider surprising (but are not).

In your case, the `read` command does not output anything to stdout (it assigns variable `NAME`), and the `echo` command does not read anything from stdin.  Since `echo` does not read anything, it executes without having to wait for anything, and therefore you see the output of `echo` right away.  The `read` command, however, needs to wait for input from its own stdin (which has nothing to do with the pipe, because the pipe is only concerned with stdout from `read`) ; `read` has its stdin connected to the terminal, so it waits for keyboard input.

In other words, your commands execute in parallel, and do not communicate with each other at all.

Remember, both commands in a pipe execute simultaneously as much as they can.  A reader that does not actually read will not bother with its writer, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Bash, in a way, interprets your entire line of code all at once - it isn't as linear as it appears. The way you have it with `|` , you are telling bash to send the output of 'read' to be the input of 'echo'. Because 'read' has no output and echo has no input, bash does the following:

1. send output ' ' to echo
2. echo ' '
3. wait for input

Based on your description, I gather you may want something more like:

```
read NAME ; echo "$NAME"
```

The `;` is like saying **first command** "and then" **second command**. `$ read foo ; echo $foo` is the same as:

```
$ read foo
$ echo $foo
```

Similarly, as pointed out by Hunter McMillen and iamauser, `&&` essentially will get the same results. `&&`, however, tells bash to execute the command following only if the command preceding was successful, while `;` is unconditional - it will execute regardless of the success of the preceding command. Another conditional way to do it is with `||`, which is like an "or" statement meaning the command following will execute only if the preceding command is UN-successful.